# Parsing binary data in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, typecasting-operator

I have read the contents of a binary file as an array of unsigned bytes but I want to interpret some of them as signed bytes. How do I do that?

```
#An array of unsigned bytes
[byte[]]$b = @(255)
#This doesn't work
[sbyte]$s = $b[0]
#Neither does this
[sbyte]$s = [convert]::ToSByte($b[0])
```

What I wanted was the value `-1`.

Comment: `function AsSignedByte { param([Byte]$Byte) [sbyte]$(if($Byte -ge 128) { $Byte - 256 } else { $Byte }) }`

Comment: Casting to an invalid value is, well, not valid (hence the error). The value is not in range. If you really want to do it, you can work around it as @PetSerAl notes.

Answer (score 1):

[The `\[System.Convert\]::ToSByte(value)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=netframework-4.7.1#Methods) raises an *OverflowException* if `value` is greater than `[sbyte]::MaxValue`.

Return to theory ([Converting from two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Converting_from_two's_complement_representation)):

```
$mask = [byte]  0x80    # [math]::pow(2,7)
$b    = [byte]  255
$s    = [sbyte] ( -($b -band $mask) + ($b -band ( -bnot $mask )) )

'result: {0,4}, {1,4} ( = 0x{0:x2}, 0x{1:x2} )' -f $b, $s
```

Output:

```
result:  255,   -1 (= 0xff, 0xff )
```

Of course, you could simplify the calculation as

```
$s    = [sbyte] ( -($b -band 0x80) + ($b -band 0x7F) )
```

**Edit** <strike>to refute [PetSerAl's doubts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085510/parsing-binary-data-in-powershell/48086736?noredirect=1#comment83149405_48086736) about `[sbyte] -($b -band $mask) + ($b -band ( -bnot $mask ))` formula correctness</strike>. [PetSerAl's doubts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085510/parsing-binary-data-in-powershell/48086736?noredirect=1#comment83149405_48086736) are right: results in Powershell-ISE differ from those in Powershell! The formula should be (see labelled parentheses)

```
#       ↓                                                ↓
[sbyte] ( -($b -band $mask) + ($b -band ( -bnot $mask )) )
#       ↑                                                ↑
```

**Proof**:

```
function AsSignedByte {     ### taken from PetSerAl's comment to the OQ
    param([Byte]$Byte) 
    [sbyte]$( if($Byte -ge 128) { $Byte - 256 } else { $Byte }) 
}

$mask = [byte]  0x80    # [math]::pow(2,7)
$good = 0
For ($i  = 0 ; $i -lt 256; $i++) {
    $b    = [byte]  $i
    $s    = [sbyte] ( -($b -band $mask) + ($b -band ( -bnot $mask )) )
    $ss   = AsSignedByte $b 
    if ( ($s -ne $ss) -or 
         ($s.GetTypeCode() -ne $ss.GetTypeCode()) -or 
         ($s -isnot [sbyte])) {
        'result: {0,4}, {1,4} ( = 0x{0:x2}, 0x{1:x2} )' -f $s, $ss
    } else { 
        $good +=1
    }
}
$good
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\48085510.ps1
256

PS D:\PShell>
```

Comment: I think `([sbyte] -($b -band $mask)) + ($b -band ( -bnot $mask ))` is not right.

Comment: @PetSerAl yes, **your** formula _with added parentheses_ is not right :)

Comment: But them added according to PowerShell precedence rules to match your formula.

Comment: And what about my post edit (formula unchanged)? Maybe you think `[sbyte] (-($b -band $mask) + ($b -band ( -bnot $mask )))`?

Comment: Change `if ( $s -ne $ss ) {` to `if ( ($s -isnot [sbyte]) -or ($s -ne $ss) ) {`

Comment: Tested `if ( ($s -ne $ss) -or ($s.GetTypeCode() -ne $ss.GetTypeCode()) -or ($s -isnot [sbyte])) {` with no change to result of `256`.

Comment: OOPS! That's difference: powershell-ISE vs. powershell :). You are right, answer updated.

Comment: Unless you have dirty session (for example `[sbyte]$s=0` somewhere), it should be no difference on PowerShell ISE vs. PowerShell console. Adding two `[sbyte]` will result in `[int]`: `([sbyte]0 + [sbyte]0) -is [int]`.